# How to setup tomcat with Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I've been spoiled by .NET development and this is driving me **NUTS**.

I am on Galileo.

Installed the [WTP](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/updates/).

Installed [tomcat 6](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-60.cgi) through the windows installer.

If I go (in eclipse) to **Window --> Preferences --> Server --> Runtime Environment** I get no tomcat option at all, as in a number of [tutorials](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/M3/tutorials/InstallTomcat.html) - only a basic folder with the useless J2EE Runtime Library.

What am doing wrong?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you install Eclipse with the J2EE development tools also? There are different version of Eclipse you can download, the standard version only comes with J2SE tools.

You should see a Tomcat folder which allows you to choose the installation folder of the version of tomcat that you choose.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I did install the full version - but I can't remember - how do I check and either way how do I go from here?

Comment: Go to Help -> About Eclipse. You should see that you have Java EE IDE installed (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.)

Comment: You put me on the right track - I installed the Java EE tools for developers from the update sites (I guess servers adapters did the trick) and now it's showing up - thanks!

Comment: In the future just download "Eclipse for Java EE developers" from their homepage instead of "Eclipse for Java developers". The Java EE variant ships with everything you need for Java EE development (WTP, server plugins, etcetera), you wouldn't need to install/add any other plugins.

Comment: @JohnIdol: it is JST Server Adapters to be more precise, this one worked for me

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments