# eclipse - add tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I want to add a tomcat server to eclipse.
I follow these instructions:

1. firstly, In Sever tabs I right click and there's New > Server
2. I select tomcat 7 and leave the other options default, which are host name, name, runtime environment. **Here, I would expect to be prompted to specify installation path** - like c:\tomcat or anything
3. I click finish
4. There's error popup - Could not load server configuration at conf.....

Thanks for helping me...

Comment: @harry Version: 3.7.0
Build id: I20110613-1736

Answer (score 0):

Probably missing **JST Server Adapters** from WTP available from eg.  http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo.

Cft.  [Apache Tomcat Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments)

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me. Was getting the same Could not load server configuration at conf message with Eclipse 3.7 Indigo (ColdFusion IDE).

Installed Tomcat 6 on Win 7.
Stop any Tomcat instances running.
Define a new server, choosing Tomcat 6.
Click Configure runtime environments...
Remove any environments.
Click Seach...
Point to Tomcat dir: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
(Should find it) Then click OK and Finish.
Start Tomcat from Eclipse.

FYI, Glassfish wasn't working for me in Eclipse so I went with Tomcat.