# How to add Tomcat Server in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I just installed Java EE plugin in plain eclipse and I am trying to add tomcat server. I opened add new server which showing "Choose the type of server to create" but  there is no server list. How can I add tomcat server?

Eclipse: Indigo.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Do as this:

`Windows -> Show View -> Servers`

Then in the Servers view, right-click and add new. It will show a pop up containing many server vendors. Under Apache select Tomcat v7.0 (Depending upon your downloaded server version). And in the run time configuration point it to the Tomcat folder you have downloaded.

You can try [this article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html). It has the info you want !!

Comment: i did and this thread was the only one about my problem. he says the server type list is empty in servers view! you get a minus one from me.

Comment: If you can't find it, look in the "others" option

Answer (score 24):

If you have the Standard Eclipse installed (instead of the JavaEE version), then you'll need to install the JavaEE web developer tools.

You can drag and drop the Install button from here:  https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-enterprise-java-and-web-developer-tools

Or you can go to Help > Install New Software then select the Eclipse site from the dropdown (Helios, Kepler depending upon your revision). Then select the option that shows Java EE. Restart Eclipse and you should see the Server list, such as Apache, Oracle, IBM etc.

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to Server tab [image]
2. Click on No servers are available. Click this link to create a new 
   server.
3. Select Tomcat V8.0 from server type list:  [image]
4. Provide path of server:
   [image]
5. Click Finish.
6. You will see server added:
   [image]
7. Right click->Start

Now you can run your web applications on server.

Answer (score 4):

If **by mistake**, you have **deleted your Tomcat Server** and Eclipse is not showing more options (**Next button will be inactive**) then in this case follow the bellow steps:

1. First remove the two files from the following path:

   - Path : workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.runtime/.settings/
   - And that two files are :

     1. org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
     2. org.eclipse.jst/server.tomcat.core.prefs
   - After deleting/removing the above two files from the workspace, Restart  the Eclipse IDE.
   - Change to the Server View, Right Click  'New', 
     Window 'Define a New Server' is shown,
     --> Select the Apache Folder, choose Tomcat-Version
   - Browse to the unzipped 'Apache-Tomcat folder', choose the second level
   - Now you are able to add/configure your new Tomcat Server. (Now you will see the '**Next**' button will become **active**, and you can then follow the normal instructions)

Answer (score 3):

There are different eclipse plugins available to manage Tomcat server and create war file.

For example you can use [tomcatPlugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html). It permits to start/stop and build the war simply.
You can read [this tutorial](http://keyboardsamurais.de/2004/01/15/tomcat_tutorial_helloworld_for_complete_fools_-_english/).

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple steps involved as you mentioned you have already installed JAVAEE plugin so the first step for you is go to `Windows->Show View->Server` in add select the AppacheTOMcat and select the tomcat version you have downloaded and set the path and start the server after that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time when we download tomcat and extract the file a folder will be created:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64
```

Inside that actual tomcat folder will be there:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
```

so while selecting you need to select inner folder:

```
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-9.0.1-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.1
```

instead of the outer.

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the server tab, go for NEW-> Server. then choose recent version of tomcat server. Click on next, and then give path for your tomcat server.(You can download tomcat server from this link https://tomcat.apache.org/download-80.cgi#8.5.32). Click on finish.

You can start your server now..!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that this post already has an accepted answer. Additionally, your answer does not provide any new suggestions. In the future, consider upvoting an existing answer instead of posting duplicate information.

Answer (score 0):

Right on the windows tab select Preferences, go for Server. then choose Runtime Environment. Click on Add, then select Apache...choose version of tomact server from this(version you installed) --> then browse the parent directory of bin of Apache tomact server--->then finsh.
Click on Windows--> selcet show view-->select server-> click on link -->choose apache--> and choose your version-->then Next -->then Finish.