# Spring web project failure

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I have a Spring HelloWorld project developed by me and for the library management I used Maven in my project. My intention is to see how Spring handles url requests.

I think I developed it correctly but, the outcome is not achieved.

I have entered my **Controller** class, **web.xml** file and the **mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml** files here.

**Controller class**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class AccessController {

    //@RequestMapping(value = {"/welcome"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model){
        System.out.println("There in an access atempt");

        model.addAttribute("message","Hello I am spring web MVC !!!");

        return "hello";

    }
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>SpringLMS</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.vigamage.controller" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

According to the way I have coded, when I enter the URL `http://localhost:8080/SpringLMS/welcome` the jsp page should be shown.

But the output I get is HTTP `Status 404, the requested resource is not available`

It does not come in to the Controller class I think.(because it does not print the sentence on the console which I have put there in the controller class.)

I cannot figure out the mistake I have done here. If you could find out where I have done it wrong, Please point it out.

This is my folder structure.

[image]

***EDIT***

**The server output**

> Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin WARNING:
>   [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting
>   property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringLMS' did not
>   find a matching property. Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   built:          Aug 19 2015 17:18:06 UTC Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Server
>   number:         7.0.64.0 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS Name:
>   Windows 8.1 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: OS
>   Version:            6.3 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Architecture:          amd64 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Java Home:
>   C:\Program Files\Java\jre7 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Version:           1.7.0_79-b15 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: JVM
>   Vendor:            Oracle Corporation Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.64 Oct 03, 2015
>   1:52:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1
>   Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.64 Oct 03, 2015
>   1:52:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO:
>   Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps
>   Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log INFO: Command
>   line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\Viraj
>   Gamage\Documents\EclipseMars\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.64\endorsed Oct
>   03, 2015 1:52:56 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener
>   log INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 Oct 03, 2015
>   1:52:56 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
>   lifecycleEvent INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which
>   allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on
>   the java.library.path: C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2013a\runtime\win64;C:\Program
>   Files\MATLAB\R2013a\bin;C:\Apache\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\sox-14-4-2;;. Oct
>   03, 2015 1:52:56 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO:
>   Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init INFO: Initializing
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load INFO: Initialization
>   processed in 775 ms Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal INFO: Starting
>   service Catalina Oct 03, 2015 1:52:56 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal INFO: Starting
>   Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.64 Oct 03, 2015 1:52:57 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
>   INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation
>   using [SHA1PRNG] took [102] milliseconds. Oct 03, 2015 1:52:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute INFO: At least one JAR
>   was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for
>   this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs
>   were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve
>   startup time and JSP compilation time. Oct 03, 2015 1:52:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log INFO: No Spring
>   WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath Oct 03, 2015
>   1:52:58 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] Oct 03, 2015 1:52:58 PM
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start INFO: Starting
>   ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"] Oct 03, 2015 1:52:58 PM
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start INFO: Server startup in
>   1829 ms

Comment: Could you provide the log output that shows what happens when your web server is started up?

Comment: Can you try to remove the mapping on the controller and add it to the `printWelcome` method and remove the project name from the url? `http://localhost:8080/welcome`

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils If you mean the thing which has been commented in the code posted here, I tried that. Still the same result

Comment: Even with the url I have in the comment? You shouldn't need to put the project directory there.

Comment: I'd suggest to move request mapping from controller and to the method like ChiefTwoPencils suggests, but you need to have the war name in the url. When you deploy your app to Tomcat, it should say which context it was deployed in (in the server output). I don't see it here, could you try redeploying and observing what is the context path. Also, what is the output you see when you try to use the url you've given?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils I think that's a war name, which needs to be there.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes it is the same result

Comment: @eis, I'm going off the img. Perhaps I'm missing something. I don't have the war in the app I've got up now but that's probably a difference of configs I guess.

Comment: @eis I think I found a reason here. In my server directory, my project has not been deployed into that. There is a deployment issue I think

Comment: so you never even deployed it?

Comment: How I made the project run was, right click-> run on server. Isn't that all I have to do?

Comment: yes, if everything is configured correctly in eclipse. Did you see any change in server output when you deployed to server?

Comment: Are you running the App from STS/IDE? if yes then  In server directory,  project may not be deployed into that.

Comment: @ArshadAli in Eclipse Juno. There is no project in server directory. Is that how it is?

Comment: there should be a war file in webapps folder of tomcat. But I asked about change in server output logs during deployment. Please check that.

Comment: @eis there is no war file in webapps folder. The server output log is attached to the question.

Comment: yes, but I asked was there a *change* in server output logs during deployment. Please try redoing the deployment and check if there are any changes during it.

Comment: @eis No any change in the server tab. It sows nothing. And the console output is shown in my question. I don't know whether I understood u correctly.

Comment: if there is no change, then deployment is not happening and you haven't configured eclipse deployment correctly.

Comment: Could you please tell me how should I do that. I have followed the normal usual procedure to do that. To make sure I removed the project from the server and added it again. Still it is same

Answer (score 2):

1) You forgot to declare your Spring Context loader, please add in your web.xml :

```
    <listener>
        <display-name>Spring Context Loader</display-name>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

2) To achieve add the **mvc:annotation-driven** element in your DispatcherServlet context, it declares explicit support for annotation-driven MVC controllers (i.e. `@RequestMapping`, `@Controller`, ...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    [...]

</beans>
```

Comment: Sorry but I have <mvc:annotation-driven /> this does not work in the case asked above??

Comment: I added that. but it gives me this `The prefix "mvc" for element "mvc:annotation-driven" is not bound.`

Comment: Still the same result too

Comment: @vigamage you need to also add schemalocation, xml namespaces like in this answer. They define the mvc namespace. (but keep the context namespace there as well, like you have)

Comment: I changed them too. no luck

Comment: did you do the redeployment and watched the logs like I asked you to?

Comment: @vigamage > i didn't watch your web.xml, i edited my answer

Comment: when I have added `<listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>` do I have to add that too? BTW it did not work :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your log output show something now; don't forget to clear your tomcat work directory and clean by clicking right on your tomcat server into Servers tab in eclipse

Comment: I cannot understand what the log output is. But in the console tab, there is nothing new than the thing I have posted in the question

Comment: How do you have add / configure your tomcat, it look strange

Comment: What I did was just added Tomcat into my project. As the accepted answer described in in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8046871/how-to-add-tomcat-server-in-eclipse

Comment: I believe your tomcat deploy path changed and Eclipse is not deploying your application. Can you paste your server config by double clicking on your tomcat server (Servers tab) or just check your deploy path / server path. Thx