# tomcat not shown in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

I have a problem about tomcat and eclipse
I want to design project ZK. I installed apache tomcat and it works.I can see it working on this url http://localhost:8080/
But I can't use tomcat in eclipse project. It is not shown in runtime servers or installed server. I tried many things in internet but I couldn't do it. What can be missed?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to add the Server Runtime Environment. In Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime Environments, click on the Add button, select the version of tomcat that you've installed, and point it to the directory in which you've installed tomcat.

Once you have a Runtime Environment, in your project, right click and select Project Properties->Server. Then select the environment you've just created.

If none of these options are available to you, install [Webtool Platform (WTP)](http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/downloads/). And then create the server runtime environment and assign the enviroment to your project, as above.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful guide, http://www.mulesoft.com/tomcat-eclipse.

Depending on the version of Eclipse you are running you may have to install the Web Tools Platform, WTP, from the eclipse download tool.

Answer (score 0):

Salaam,

I find [this: sysdeo :plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) very useful.

- install: under plugins dir @ eclipse
- config: enter your tomcat install root (different instance for each workspace)
- start/stop/reload buttons
- log redirect to console

You can also use ant scripts to control tomcat server

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that when creating a new `Dynamic Web Project`, in `EAR Membership -> EAR Project Name` checkbox is unchecked
[image]