# No server in Eclipse; trying to install Tomcat

Tags: eclipse

I'm trying to install Tomcat in Eclipse but I can't get a server tab to show up.
When I go to *Window -> Show View -> Other* and type in "server", I don't get any results.

When I go to *File -> New -> Other* and type 'server' I also get nothing.

Does anyone know what happened to my servers and where I can find them? (I've never used Eclipse with servers before).

Comment: Which Eclipse download are you using?  It should be the IDE for Java EE, or one into which you've installed WTP's Java EE Tools.

Comment: This is the version info: Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 1.4.2.20120213-0813 \ epp.package.java \ null   What is WTP, and how do I verify it's for Java EE?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Try to install `JST Server Adapters` and `JST Server Adapters Extentions`. I am running Eclipse 4.4.2 Luna and it worked.

Here are the steps I followed:

> 1. Help -> Install New Software
> 2. Choose "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" site
> 3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
> 4. Check JST Server Adapters and JST Server Adapters Extentions

Comment: It also works for me. I am using Eclipse Neon. Thanks a lot

Comment: This is obvious, but we should try this in "Eclipse for Java EE developers" instead of regular Eclipse edition.

Comment: @Poulad this worked for me in "Eclipse for Java EE developers"

Answer (score 35):

For future poeple who have the same problem: Try to add server tab from eclipse menu, if it doesnt work, then go do @Tomasz Bartnik solution above, and retry the following again:

1. Go to WIndow > Show view > Other

   [image]
2. search for `servers`, select it and press OK

   [image]

It will then be added to your tabs

Comment: There is no an option named `Servers`.

Comment: No worries, you need to go to Help>Eclipse Marketplace . Then type server in the search box it will display Eclipse JST Server Adapters (Apache Tomcat,...) .Select that one and install it .Then It will appear in the list

Answer (score 30):

The reason you might not be getting any results is because you might not be having the J2EE environment setup in your Eclipse IDE. Follow these steps to solve the problem.

1. Goto Help -> Install new Software
2. Select {Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen} (or Similar option/version) in the "Work with" tab.
3. Search for Web,XML,Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
4. Check the boxes corresponding to,

   - Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
   - JST Server Adapters
   - JST Server Adapters Extensions
5. Click next and accept the license agreement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up installing a new copy of Eclipse - JAVA EE, and it all works now.

Answer (score 4):

The [Web Tools Platform](http://eclipse.org/webtools/) provides the Java EE development tools, and is included in the IDE for Java EE Developers.  Among other things, it provides the Servers view and makes it easy to launch a Tomcat server from there.  You can either download the IDE for Java EE Developers, or go to the Help menu and Install New Software, looking for the Java EE features.

Comment: What exact features should be installed? I added   Eclipse Java Web Developer Tools 3.6.1.v201409111852 org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group but it seems to be not enough.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24234148/cannot-install-apache-tomcat-in-eclipse/27859031#27859031

Comment: Here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Comment: Look for the one that calls itself the "Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools".

Comment: but when i downloaded it it kept still on 48%

Answer (score 4):

Steps to follow:

```
1.Goto Help -> Install new Software
2.Give address http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen and name as your choice.
3.Search for Java EE and choose 1.Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 
4.Search for JST and choose 2.JST Server Adapters 3.JST Server Adapters Extensions
5.Click next and accept the license agreement.
```

Find the server option in the window-->preferences and add server as you need

Answer (score 3):

1. In {workspace-directory}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings delete the following two files:

   - org.eclipse.wst.server.core.prefs
   - org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.prefs
2. Restart Eclipse

Answer (score 3):

The reason you might not be getting any results is because you might not be having the J2EE environment setup in your Eclipse IDE. Follow these steps to solve the problem.

1. Goto Help -> Install new Software
   Select relevant dropdown entry {Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/<?>} (or Similar
   option/version) in the "Work with" tab.
2. Search for Web,XML,Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
   Check the boxes corresponding to,Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools
   JST Server Adapters
   JST Server Adapters Extensions
   Click next and accept the license agreement.

Answer (score 2):

Download the tomcat latest zip from 
https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi
Rename the folder with simple name like 'tomcat'.
Save the folder and copy the path.

Goto Help -> Install new Software
Select {Oxygen - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen} in the "Work with" tab.
Select the last option Web,XML,Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development
Check the boxes corresponding to 1.Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools 2.JST Server Adapters 3.JST Server Adapters Extensions Click next and accept the license agreement.

Answer (score 2):

You can install Tomcat server form Eclipse market place.

Help -> Eclipse Market Place search for 'Tomcat'  -> Install Eclipse Tomcat plugin.

[image]

After installation restart eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 'Servers' doesn't exist.
Therefore download correct Eclipse IDE. It is Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers(Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers). This way is easy.

Answer (score 2):

You have probably installed Eclipse for Java Developers instead of Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers, server tab and some other are not available.

You don't have to uninstall. Just rerun eclipse-inst-win64.exe and choose Java EE IDE

[JAVA EE IDE Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brqdo.jpg)