# Cannot install Apache Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, installation

I've downloaded apache-tomcat-8.0.8 archive, then I've unzipped it and tried to add it in Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments by clicking Search and selecting path to the uzipped archive. What I'm getting is Server Error

> No new server runtime environments were found.

Any ideas why it might be happening? I have no Apache Tomcat options in New Server Runtime Environment window, which I get by clicking Add in the previous one. There are such options in every tutorial I read.

Answer (score 0):

I think there currently is no adapter for Tomcat 8 in Eclipse.

**Updated**

Don't use the search button. Click add and choose an adapter first. Open Apache and choose Tomcat 7. Click next and point the installation directory at your Tomcat folder.

Comment: How about Tomcat 7? I've tried that also, with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have Eclipse without Java EE components.

so you see something like

[image]

instead of

[image]

Check [Apache Tomcat Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments) (need to install **JST Server Adapters** )

Once you have plugins installed follow dialog flow e.g. like

http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.server.ui.doc.user%2Ftopics%2Ftomcat.html

Answer (score 0):

Seems like no java EE component. 
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers 'Servers' doesn't exist.

Therefore download correct Eclipse IDE. It is Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers(Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers).

Then,
Open Eclipse IDE > Click on the Servers tab located at the bottom > right click > New > click on Server.
Select Apache and then select the appropriate version of tomcat server.click Next.
Select tomcat Installation Directory and JRE. Click next.Click Finish.