# How to enable "Browse Deployment Location..." context menu item in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, location, menuitem

In the previous versions of Eclipse this menu item was available in the context menu (right-click on the server in the "Servers" view):

- Eclipse **Luna** (version 4.4.0) [has this menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVf6o.png)
- Eclipse **Mars** (version 4.5.2) [doesn't have this menu item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QMJg.png)

Why is it missing now?

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but try this:

1. Go to *Help->Install New Software*
2. Choose "Luna - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" site
3. Expand "Web, XML, and Java EE Development"
4. Check **JST Server Adapters** and **JST Server Adapters Extentions**

> NOTE: If already checked try to reinstall + try to reinstall [Eclipse
>   WebTools](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/)

---

Resources:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32739665/5364144

Comment: This does not work for me in Oxygen. Both are already installed, all works ok, except I do not have "Browse Deployment Location" in the server context menu...

Comment: @MauroMolinari , did you find a solution?

Comment: @Dikla no, I did not. My suspect is that the mentioned menu item is only available if you install the whole Eclipse JEE package, while my installation is a Runtime Platform + WTP plugins installed one by one. In theory, this should be equivalent, but in practice I was not able to get that option show in my Server context menu.