# Tomcat 6 configuration inside Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I am having trouble configuring my `Eclipse EE` to run Tomcat 6 (my company has not migrated to Tomcat 7 yet).  I was trying to follow [these instructions](http://www.coreservlets.com/Apache-Tomcat-Tutorial/eclipse.html).  I went into the servers tab in the bottom panel, hit `New->Server`, then chose `Apache->Tomcat 6`.  Then I went through a succession of the following screens:

[image]
[image]

and finally arrived to the error message:

[image]

Here are the contents of my Tomcat conf dir (`C:\home\SFTWR\tomcat6\conf`):

```
catalina.policy
catalina.properties
context.xml
logging.properties
server.xml
web.xml
wrapper.properties
```

Any suggestion what may be wrong?  It runs fine when running standalone and I can deploy apps from Eclipse but I would like to be able to run in in Eclipse for debugging purposes.

**UPDATE:**

Despite the error message, I noticed that the server was indeed registered, however, not functional -- when I tried to hit "Start", I got an error popup listing two problems:

- **Publishing to localhost**  (Details: *Cannot publish to the server because it is missing its runtime environment.)*
- **Starting localhost**  (Details:  *An internal error occurred during: "Starting localhost".
  java.lang.NullPointerException*)

The detailed exception stack trace is as follows:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not load the Tomcat server configuration at \Servers\localhost-config. The configuration may be corrupt or incomplete.
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.Tomcat60Configuration.load(Tomcat60Configuration.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServer.getTomcatConfiguration(TomcatServer.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getTomcatConfiguration(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.setupLaunch(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.launch(TomcatLaunchConfigurationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:854)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:696)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl2(Server.java:3402)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.startImpl(Server.java:3340)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$StartJob.run(Server.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
```

Comment: What does it say when you click 'Details >>'

Comment: just posted an update with the info you requested.  thanks

Comment: Any errors in your Error log that are relevant?  Window > Show View > Other... > General > Error log

Comment: added the detailed exception stack to OP. thanks

Comment: I was having this problem with the buggy 6.0.32 version.  Once I installed 6.0.36, I was able to register a server

Comment: however, the new problem is that i cannot access the app in a browser when running in Eclipse (console is fine): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124415/cannot-connect-to-instance-of-tomcat-6-started-in-eclipse

Comment: Better try this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments

Answer (score 2):

I seem to have had the same problem with Eclipse Juno and Tomcat 6.0_36 on Centos 6.3. It took me 2 days to realize that the problem only existed when the Tomcat server was started before Eclipse was started (e.g. at boot time).

Executing "/etc/init.d/tomcat stop" before starting Eclipse solved my problem.