# Adding Tomcat into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I am trying to add a Tomcat server into runtime environments. I successfully installed Tomcat. I already have Java EE eclipse, BUT after I click search under Window->Preferences->Server->Runtime environments and select Apache Tomcat and then click OK a window with the following text popups:

> No new server runtime environments were found.

What am I doing wrong? I thought after switching to Java EE and installing tomcat I will be able to add the RE.

### Update

After trying to add the RE: no tomcat servers list:

[image]

After trying to search (C:/Program Files/Apache...):

[image]

And finally the popup after choosing "apache software foundation" and hitting OK:

[image]

Comment: Just click "Download additional server adapters" to install Tomcat server adapter?

Comment: Probably you downloaded Eclipse plain Java version instead of Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers distribution.

If this, you can install Java EE plugins via Eclipse Update Manager. Then you can see "servers" window.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the server runtime in that window. From the browse button, select the base path of the directory where you have installed tomcat and hit next. Hopefully that should do it. There should also be an option to download and install, if you have internet connectivity.

If you dont see any server types in the 'add new Server' dialog, then you are probably missing the server adapters. In which case click on the 'Download additional server adapters' link. This will allow you to pick and download 'tomcat server adapter'. Once that is done.

[image: Add New Server]

[image: Add New Server]

Some screenshots etc would also help in understanding and helping you resolve your issue.

Hope this helps.

Comment: the problem is, that I can not select ANY version of tomcat like on 1st screenshot while defining a new server

Comment: Can you put some screenshots etc for more details. Its hard to understand why you cannot select any version of tomcat.

Comment: Click on the 'Download additional server adapters' link (as you see in the first screenshot). This will allow you to pick and download 'tomcat server adapter'. Once that is done. You should be able to see the servers in the list and follow the steps I have provided. On a side note, if you are planning to build Spring based web applications, try installing STS which in my opinion makes a web engineers like much easier. Especially the things you are struggling with would already be ready for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, no tomcat adapter were in the list of adapters. I appreciate your help, guys

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Then my recommendation would be just install 'STS' - http://www.springsource.org/sts It would probably take less time to do fresh install of STS. You would also benefit from the tons of neat features that come with it.

Answer (score 4):

Run time environment click on add button select Apache tomcat-> Click on next button -> Browse the Tomcat 7.0 path -> Finish.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are not having JST server adapters...you are not able to see installed apache in eclipse ....just install this through 'install new software' in help menu ....

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely are missing the Eclipse Tomcat Server Feature. You can either try reinstalling all of the [WTP plugins](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/) or maybe install Spring STS which I'm sure has the plugin installed.