# Tomcat server not listed on Target Runtime on eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-neon

I want to create dynamic web project on eclipse neon but i can't find the tomcat server on the Target Run time list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Tomcat Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments)

Answer (score 3):

I am also using Eclipse neon and I faced the same problem and the answer was available in [Apache Tomcat Not Showing in Eclipse Server Runtime Environments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000078/apache-tomcat-not-showing-in-eclipse-server-runtime-environments) on SO.

**Of the Available Answers the below steps Worked for me:**

1.Help-->Eclipse Marketplace

2.Type Tomcat in search box and choose the Option JST Server Adapters(Apache Tomcat,...) and click on Install

3.Then complete the Simple installation steps and after installation Eclipse prompts for a restart accept and then you can see the Target Run time updated with Tomcat server

Comment: If you think the answer already exists on SO you may flag the question as a duplicate instead of posting a new answer. This keeps the site clean and reduces the amount of duplicate answer on the site.

Comment: However, if one thinks the new question differs even slightly and answers to the previous question address the new question partially then it is better to post a new answer this will help the poster anyways which is the ultimate purpose of SO after all.